# Error handling with function prototype in C

Tags: c, error-handling

Trying to figure out error handling in C for the function prototype "chars_to_int".

I am posting my code with the body to show a better picture. I want my code to output an error if "chars_to_int" encountered an error and I am looking to see if chars_to_int == NULL is the correct way? How can I test this?

Also, is there another way to implement the Error null in the main body to keep it all together?

Thank you.

```
int chars_to_int(char*, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s 0[bqsutx]<number>", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    char *chars = argv[1];

    int result = 0;

    if (chars[1] == 'b') {
        result = chars_to_int(chars, 2);
    } else if (chars[1] == 'q') {
        result = chars_to_int(chars, 4);
    } else if (chars[1] == 's') {
        result = chars_to_int(chars, 6);
    } else if (chars[1] == 'u') {
        result = chars_to_int(chars, 11);
    } else if (chars[1] == 't') {
        result = chars_to_int(chars, 14);
    } else if (chars[1] == 'x') {
        result = chars_to_int(chars, 16);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Base is incorrect.");
    }

    if (chars_to_int != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "chars_to_int has encountered an error.");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This statement if (chars_to_int == NULL) { does not make sense. Pointer to an defined function can not be equal to NULL.

Comment: There's a lot that is wrong in this code. Assuming there is a command line parameter, there's a presumption it is at least 2 characters long ( `chars[1]` ). The first error message doesn't stop processing at that point... NULL is usually 0, so there's no distinction between the asked "error return" and the return of an integer value... Back to the drawing board, it would seem. (And the standard library `strtol()` functions provide the 'radix' translations, making re-inventing the wheel a silly thing to do.) PS: Hex is usually considered _unsigned_, too...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Any tips on the topic? I actually have the full code done properly already, I just posted bits of the main body for show and ask if you could connect the two if statements.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I found this from googling, any tips?

Comment: What does `char_to_int` *return* when it encounters an error? Check for that.

Comment: @Cheatah edited code above, would this work and how could I test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP, in comment, says the shown code was "abridged".

Here's code that compiles and runs and uses standard library functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    // Test arguments. exit when necessary...
    if( argc < 2 || strlen( argv[1] ) < 3 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Get serious!\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    // one of many ways to translate a character value to an integer
    int radix = 0, result;
         if( argv[1][1] == 'b') radix = 2;
    else if( argv[1][1] == 'q') radix = 4;
    else if( argv[1][1] == 's') radix = 6;
    else if( argv[1][1] == 'u') radix = 11;
    else if( argv[1][1] == 't') radix = 14;
    else if( argv[1][1] == 'x') radix = 16;

    // Use a standard library function
    // Adapting to suit unsigned hexadecimal left as an exercise for the reader.
    char *rest = NULL;
    if( radix )
        result = strtol( &argv[1][2], &rest, radix );

    // As requested, a single point where failure is tested to halt execution
    if( !radix || rest[0] != '\0' ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Encountered an error.\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "%d\n", result );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it but I was trying to only used simple code without any other libraries, it is my first time using C. Why are you returning 1 for error handling and not returning -1?

Comment: Two things: 1. The libraries are tested code. Have fun writing your own versions, but use standard libraries in the real world. 2. Any non-zero return. is conventional error condition. Even <stdlib.h> defines EXIT_FAILURE to be 1... (too much typing) Cheers...